# WixToolset cannot be installed inside a windows container having base image of windows/servercore

Tags: docker, installation, build-tools, windows-container

I am trying to install WixToolset 3.11.1 inside a running windows container based on image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore`. I am using the chocolatey command `choco install wixtoolset` but the .NET 3.5 fails to install and the installation is stuck. I tried the same command by adding it to the Dockerfile to install it during the image build, but the error is the same. Is there a way to get wixtoolset installed inside a windows container or am I missing something in this process?

Below is the log after I run the install command:

```
PS C:\> choco install -y -r --no-progress wixtoolset
Installing the following packages:
wixtoolset
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.

DotNet3.5 v3.5.20160716 [Approved]
dotnet3.5 package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
#< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><Obj S="progress" RefId="0"><TN RefId="0"><T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T><T>System.Object</T></TN><MS><I64 N="SourceId">1</I64><PR N="Record"><AV>Preparing modules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj><Obj S="progress" RefId="1"><TNRef RefId="0" /><MS><I64 N="SourceId">1</I64><PR N="Record"><AV>Preparing modules for first use.</AV><AI>0</AI><Nil /><PI>-1</PI><PC>-1</PC><T>Completed</T><SR>-1</SR><SD> </SD></PR></MS></Obj><S S="debug">Host version is 5.1.17763.316, PowerShell Version is '5.1.17763.316' and CLR Version is '4.0.30319.42000'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Format-FileSize'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ChecksumValid'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ChocolateyUnzip'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ChocolateyWebFile'.</S><S
S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-EnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-EnvironmentVariableNames'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-FtpFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-OSArchitectureWidth'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-PackageParameters'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-PackageParametersBuiltIn'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ToolsLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-UACEnabled'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-UninstallRegistryKey'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VirusCheckValid'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebFileName'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebHeaders'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyDesktopLink'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyExplorerMenuItem'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPath'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPowershellCommand'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyShortcut'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyVsixPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyZipPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-Vsix'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Set-EnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Set-PowerShellExitCode'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Test-ProcessAdminRights'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function
'Uninstall-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Update-SessionEnvironment'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Write-ChocolateyFailure'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Write-ChocolateySuccess'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Write-FileUpdateLog'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Write-FunctionCallLogMessage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Get-ProcessorBits'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Get-OSBitness'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Get-InstallRegistryKey'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Generate-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Add-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Start-ChocolateyProcess'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Invoke-ChocolateyProcess'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Remove-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'refreshenv'.</S><S S="debug">Loading community extensions</S><S S="debug">Importing 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-core\chocolatey-core.psm1'</S><S S="verbose">Loading module from path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-core\chocolatey-core.psm1'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-UninstallRegistryKey'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-AppInstallLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-AvailableDriveLetter'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-EffectiveProxy'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-PackageCacheLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-PackageParameters'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebContent'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Register-Application'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-AppInstallLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-AvailableDriveLetter'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-EffectiveProxy'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-PackageCacheLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-PackageParameters'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-UninstallRegistryKey'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-WebContent'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Register-Application'.</S><S S="debug">Importing 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-visualstudio\chocolatey-visualstudio.extension.psm1'</S><S S="verbose">Loading module from path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-visualstudio\chocolatey-visualstudio.extension.psm1'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Add-VisualStudioComponent'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Add-VisualStudioWorkload'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudioInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudioInstallerHealth'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudioInstance'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudioVsixInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-VisualStudio'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-VisualStudioInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-VisualStudioVsixExtension'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Remove-VisualStudioComponent'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Remove-VisualStudioProduct'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Remove-VisualStudioWorkload'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-VisualStudio'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-VisualStudioVsixExtension'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Add-VisualStudioComponent'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Add-VisualStudioWorkload'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-VisualStudioInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-VisualStudioInstallerHealth'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-VisualStudioInstance'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Get-VisualStudioVsixInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Install-VisualStudio'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Install-VisualStudioInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Install-VisualStudioVsixExtension'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Remove-VisualStudioComponent'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Remove-VisualStudioProduct'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function
'Remove-VisualStudioWorkload'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Uninstall-VisualStudio'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Uninstall-VisualStudioVsixExtension'.</S><S S="debug">Importing 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-windowsupdate\chocolatey-windowsupdate.psm1'</S><S S="verbose">Loading module from path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-windowsupdate\chocolatey-windowsupdate.psm1'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-WindowsUpdate'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Test-WindowsUpdate'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Install-WindowsUpdate'.</S><S S="verbose">Importing function 'Test-WindowsUpdate'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Format-FileSize'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ChecksumValid'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ChocolateyUnzip'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ChocolateyWebFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-EnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-EnvironmentVariableNames'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-FtpFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-OSArchitectureWidth'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-PackageParameters'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-PackageParametersBuiltIn'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-ToolsLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-UACEnabled'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-UninstallRegistryKey'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VirusCheckValid'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebFileName'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebHeaders'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyDesktopLink'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyExplorerMenuItem'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPath'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyPowershellCommand'.</S><S
S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyShortcut'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyVsixPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyZipPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-Vsix'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Set-EnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Set-PowerShellExitCode'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Test-ProcessAdminRights'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Update-SessionEnvironment'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Write-ChocolateyFailure'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'xPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-ChocolateyZipPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-Vsix'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Set-EnvironmentVariab
le'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Set-PowerShellExitCode'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Test-ProcessAdm
inRights'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Unins
tall-ChocolateyPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Update-SessionEnvironment'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting fu
nction 'Write-ChocolateyFailure'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Write-ChocolateySuccess'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Write-FileUpdateLog'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting functi
on 'Write-FunctionCallLogMessage'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-AppInstallLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-AvailableDriveLetter'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting f
unction 'Get-EffectiveProxy'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-PackageCacheLocation'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-WebContent'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Regi
ster-Application'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Add-VisualStudioComponent'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Add-VisualStudioWorkload'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-
VisualStudioInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudioInstallerHealth'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Get-VisualStudioInstance'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting fun
ction 'Get-VisualStudioVsixInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-VisualStudio'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-VisualStudioInstaller'.</S><S S="verbose">Expo
rting function 'Install-VisualStudioVsixExtension'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Remove-VisualStudioComponent'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Remove-VisualStudioProduct'.</S><
S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Remove-VisualStudioWorkload'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-VisualStudio'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Uninstall-VisualStudioVsixE
xtension'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Install-WindowsUpdate'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting function 'Test-WindowsUpdate'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Get-ProcessorBits'.</S><S
 S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Get-OSBitness'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Get-InstallRegistryKey'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Generate-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alia
s 'Add-BinFile'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Start-ChocolateyProcess'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Invoke-ChocolateyProcess'.</S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'Remove-BinFile'.<
/S><S S="verbose">Exporting alias 'refreshenv'.</S></Objs>
ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat Text -OutputFormat Text -EncodedCommand IAAg
ACAAIAAgACAAJABuAG8AUwBsAGUAZQBwACAAPQAgACQAVAByAHUAZQANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIwAkAGUAbgB2ADoAQwBoAG8AYwBvAGwAYQB0AGUAeQBFAG4AdgBpAHIAbwBuAG0AZQBuAHQARABlAGIAdQBnAD0AJwBmAGEAbABzAGUAJwANAAoAIAAg
ACAAIAAgACAAIwAkAGUAbgB2ADoAQwBoAG8AYwBvAGwAYQB0AGUAeQBFAG4AdgBpAHIAbwBuAG0AZQBuAHQAVgBlAHIAYgBvAHMAZQA9ACcAZgBhAGwAcwBlACcADQAKACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACYAIABpAG0AcABvAHIAdAAtAG0AbwBkAHUAbABlACAALQBu
AGEAbQBlACAAJwBDADoAXABQAHIAbwBnAHIAYQBtAEQAYQB0AGEAXABjAGgAbwBjAG8AbABhAHQAZQB5AFwAaABlAGwAcABlAHIAcwBcAGMAaABvAGMAbwBsAGEAdABlAHkASQBuAHMAdABhAGwAbABlAHIALgBwAHMAbQAxACcAIAAtAFYAZQByAGIAbwBz
AGUAOgAkAGYAYQBsAHMAZQAgAHwAIABPAHUAdAAtAE4AdQBsAGwAOwANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAdAByAHkAewANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACQAcAByAG8AZwByAGUAcwBzAFAAcgBlAGYAZQByAGUAbgBjAGUAPQAiAFMAaQBsAGUAbgB0AGwAeQBD
AG8AbgB0AGkAbgB1AGUAIgANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgAGMAbQBkAC4AZQB4AGUAIAAvAGMAIABEAEkAUwBNACAALwBPAG4AbABpAG4AZQAgAC8ATgBvAFIAZQBzAHQAYQByAHQAIAAvAEUAbgBhAGIAbABlAC0ARgBlAGEAdAB1AHIAZQAgAC8ARgBl
AGEAdAB1AHIAZQBOAGEAbQBlADoATgBlAHQARgB4ADMADQAKACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIABpAGYAKAAhACQAbgBvAFMAbABlAGUAcAApAHsAcwB0AGEAcgB0AC0AcwBsAGUAZQBwACAANgB9AA0ACgAgACAAIAAgACAAIAB9AA0ACgAgACAAIAAgACAAIABj
AGEAdABjAGgAewANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAAgAGkAZgAoACEAJABuAG8AUwBsAGUAZQBwACkAewBzAHQAYQByAHQALQBzAGwAZQBlAHAAIAA4AH0ADQAKACAAIAAgACAAIAAgACAAIAB0AGgAcgBvAHcADQAKACAAIAAgACAAIAAgAH0A] was not su
ccessful. Exit code was '1'. See log for possible error messages.
The install of dotnet3.5 was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\DotNet3.5\Tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

wixtoolset v3.11.1 [Approved]
wixtoolset package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Installing wixtoolset...
```

Comment: It would seem like Microsoft secretly solved installing .NET 3.5 runtimes: https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/3.5/runtime/windowsservercore-1903/Dockerfile After install the wixtoolset and its dependency DotNet3.5 will install properly (or rather do nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET Framework 3.5 feature can only be installed from the \Sources\sxs folder off the installation ISO...so `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore` won't work (unless you manually copy in the .cab files in and use DISM to install them.)

Luckily, Microsoft provides containers specifically suited for running Framework apps:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework

- [dotnet/framework/sdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk/): .NET Framework SDK
- [dotnet/framework/aspnet](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet/): ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC
- [dotnet/framework/runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/): .NET Framework Runtime
- [dotnet/framework/wcf](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-wcf/): Windows Communication Framework (WCF)
- [dotnet/framework/samples](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-samples/): .NET Framework, ASP.NET and WCF Samples

For my situation, using `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:3.5` allowed me to install the WixToolset package from Chocolatey.

---

**EDIT 2022-08-15**: Including Dockerfile from Andreas comment below, since it's no longer part of the primary branch in Microsoft's repo:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903

# Install .NET Fx 3.5
RUN curl -fSLo microsoft-windows-netfx3.zip https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/dockerassets/microsoft-windows-netfx3-1903.zip `
    && tar -zxf microsoft-windows-netfx3.zip `
    && del /F /Q microsoft-windows-netfx3.zip `
    && DISM /Online /Quiet /Add-Package /PackagePath:.\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab `
    && del microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab `
    && powershell Remove-Item -Force -Recurse ${Env:TEMP}\*

# Apply latest patch
RUN curl -fSLo patch.msu http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2019/09/windows10.0-kb4515871-x64_03a6aec54b0ca2fc40efcff09a810064f5d2ae60.msu `
    && mkdir patch `
    && expand patch.msu patch -F:* `
    && del /F /Q patch.msu `
    && DISM /Online /Quiet /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\patch\Windows10.0-kb4515871-x64.cab `
    && rmdir /S /Q patch

# ngen .NET Fx
ENV COMPLUS_NGenProtectedProcess_FeatureEnabled 0
RUN \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen uninstall "Microsoft.Tpm.Commands, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=amd64" `
    && \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen update `
    && \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen update
```

Comment: The 3.5 tag is a dockerfile defined top of servercore which shows how to do it: https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/3.5/runtime/windowsservercore-1903/Dockerfile

Comment: @Andreas Link doesn't work. Since I am not so familiar with yaml, could someone show a more complete example, instead of only a 'FROM' snippet?

Comment: @ffonz - I went to the commit from the day Andreas posted - this should work:  https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/062715aec03a503f9e005203adddb7231c855a1b/3.5/runtime/windowsservercore-1903/Dockerfile

Comment: @ffonz I  included a copy in the original answer in case the repo ever goes away.

Answer (score 6):

I was lucky using the following command before installing wix:

```
powershell Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, you just save my life. I've been tried several solutions (including above) still no luck in GitLab Windows shared runner. Except you!

Snippet of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```xml
stages:
 - build
 - test

build:
 stage: build
 before_script:
 - Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core
 - choco install wixtoolset --version 3.11.2 -y
tags:
 - shared-windows
 - windows
 - windows-1809
```

Comment: @yancyn I was using Travis-CI but essentially same flow. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. ERROR : “The install of dotnet3.5 was NOT successful”.

Following set of commands worked for me:

```
ENV CHOCO_URL=https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
 [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Tls,Tls11,Tls12'; `
 iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("$env:CHOCO_URL"));
 
RUN choco install nuget.commandline -y --force
RUN nuget install WiX.Toolset
```

This will install chocolatey. Which can be used to install nuget commands line. Installing WiX via nuget worked well, since there is an known issue with chocolatey install of Wix.

Note: This command installed WiX.Toolset.3.9.1208 in the image. I've seen 3.11 and even .0 preview.